# What does the RMS value of a DC current waveform represent?

Tags: power, current, pulse, rms, square

I understand (or at least think I understand) the math and calculation of RMS values and that it generally is used for representing equivalent power of non-DC circuits, like typical sinusoidal AC circuits, but it should also be useful in DC circuits for the same purpose.

There seems to be a discrepancy in the DC cases that I cannot find an answer for, and I feel like I must be missing something like it's so obvious that no reference material or classes mention it.

For example: the simple circuit below with 5 V DC supply and 100 Ω resistor that is switched at duty cycle D=75%.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs6mNJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming everything is ideal, what is the power dissipated by the resistor?

If **\$P = V_{avg} × I_{avg}\$** 
then **\$P = 5 V × 0.05 A × 0.75 = 0.1875 W\$**, but the RMS value of the pulsed current waveform is **\$I_{PK} × \sqrt{D}\$**.

So if **\$P = V_{RMS} × I_{RMS}\$** and **\$I_{RMS} = 0.05 A × \sqrt{0.75}\$** 
then **\$P = 0.217 W\$**

- Why the discrepancy?
- The first number is correct, so what does that second number represent, or is it a meaningless value?

Comment: The first number is correct but this isn't: \$P=V_{avg}\times I_{avg}\$.

Comment: according to the first equation it should be 5V x 0.75 x 0.05A x 0.75. You missed an extra 0.75. Actually in both cases you forgot about the fact the voltage is only on 0.75 of the time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the titular question, what is RMS, it is the equivalent DC that would dissipate the same power in a *resistive* load. For instance, a 240V AC RMS sinusoid actually has peaks of ±340V, but it would dissipate the same power in a fixed resistance as a steady 240V DC. Likewise, 10A RMS of alternating current through some resistance would deliver the same amount of power as a constant 10A DC.

Because we are dealing with power, which is proportional to the *square* of voltage and current, giving rise to the famous power expressions \$\frac{V^2}{R}\$ and \$I^2R\$, we cannot rely on *average* values of current or voltage to perform power calculations, except under very particular circumstances. This becomes abundantly clear when we consider:

- Current through a resistor in *either* direction causes the resistor to heat up (receive) energy, so power in the resistor is positive whether the current through it is positive *or* negative.
- The *average* value of a sinusoidal signal (or any signal symmetrical above and below zero) is zero, but obviously an alternating voltage across or current through a resistor does *not* result in zero power being delivered to the resistor.

Now, onto your particular case:

Average current is \$I_{AVG} = 0.75 \times 50mA = 37.5mA\$.

Average voltage is \$V_{AVG} = 0.75 \times 5V = 3.75V\$.

You incorrectly said that power would be \$V_{AVG} \times I_{AVG}\$, but then you calculated that as:

$$ P = 5V \times 0.05A \times 0.75 = 0.1875W $$

That's the correct answer, for average power, but it's not \$V_{AVG} \times I_{AVG}\$!

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{AVG} \times I_{AVG} &= (5V \times 0.75) \times (50mA \times 0.75) \\ \\
&= (0.75)^2 \times 5V \times 50mA \\ \\
&= 140mW
\end{aligned}
$$

This is *not* the correct value for average power. The formula for *apparent* power is:

$$ P = V_{RMS} \times I_{RMS} $$

<sub>Note: for a purely resistive load, like yours, this expression for so-called "apparent power" does tell you the power dissipated in the load (as heat). However, as user @PeterGreen points out, it does not account for phase difference between current and voltage, and so cannot be used to determine the *true*, net power delivered to *reactive* loads. If the load is in any way able to store energy and/or return it to the source (such as capacitance or inductance), you must take an alternative approach to obtain true power.</sub>

For a rectangular signal, RMS value is not the same as the average value.

For some signal \$V(t)\$, its RMS is the square root of the ***average of \$V(t)^2\$***. The "average of the square" is very different from the "square of the average", which is where I think you went wrong, but accidentally got the right answer.

For a rectangular signal with 75% duty cycle, RMS will be the **R**oot of the **M**ean of the **S**quare:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{RMS} &= \sqrt{ \frac{75\% \times V^2 + 25\% \times 0^2}{100\%} }\\ \\
&= \sqrt{75\% \times V^2} \\ \\
&= \sqrt{75\% \times (5V)^2} \\ \\
&= 4.33V
\end{aligned}
$$

Similarly, RMS current will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{RMS} &= \sqrt{75\% \times I^2} \\ \\
&= \sqrt{75\% \times (50mA)^2} \\ \\
&= 43.3mA \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

To find power, we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= V_{RMS} \times I_{RMS} \\ \\
&= 4.33V \times 43.3mA \\ \\
& = 187.5mW
\end{aligned}
$$

or

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= \frac{{V_{RMS}}^2}{R} \\ \\
&= \frac{(4.33V)^2}{100\Omega} \\ \\
& = 187.5mW \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

or

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= {I_{RMS}}^2R \\ \\
&= (43.3mA)^2 \times 100\Omega \\ \\
& = 187.5mW \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

or, ***average*** power. Remembering that \$P_{100\%} = 5V \times 50mA = 250mW \$, average power at 75% duty cycle will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{75\%} &= 75\% \times P_{100\%} \\ \\
&= 0.75 \times 250mW \\ \\
& = 187.5mW \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

If you look closely, this last calculation is what you "accidentally" performed to arrive at the correct answer!

Comment: BTW P=Vrms×Irms is only true if V is proportional to I (which is true in the OP's circuit but not always).

Answer (score 6):

Follow along:

$$\begin{align*}
\overline{P}&=f\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{f}} \frac{V_t^2}{R}\:\text{d}t\\\\&=\frac{f}{R}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{f}} V_t^2\:\text{d}t\\\\&=\frac{f}{R}\left\{\int_{0}^{\frac{0.75}{f}} V^2\:\text{d}t+\int_{0}^{\frac{0.25}{f} } 0\:\text{d}t\right\}\\\\&=\frac{f\,V^2}{R}\int_{0}^{\frac{0.75}{f}} \text{d}t\\\\
&=\frac{f\,V^2}{R}\left[\vphantom{\frac{f\,V^2}{R}\int_{0}^{\frac{0.75}{f}} \text{d}t}t\right]_0^\frac{0.75}{f}\\\\
&=\frac{f\,V^2}{R}\left[\vphantom{\frac{f\,V^2}{R}\int_{0}^{\frac{0.75}{f}} \text{d}t}\frac{0.75}{f}-0\right]
\\\\
&=\frac34\frac{V^2}{R}=\frac{\left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}V\right]^2}{R}
\end{align*}$$

From this, it's easy to see that \$V_{_\text{RMS}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}V\$ for a 75% duty cycle. Here, at 75% duty, \$V_{_\text{RMS}}\approx 4.33\:\text{V}\$.

The same process using \$I_t\$ instead of \$V_t\$ would get you to the exact same result.

$$\begin{align*}
\overline{P}&=f\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{f}} I_t^2\,R\:\text{d}t\\\\&=f\,R\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{f}} I_t^2\:\text{d}t\\\\
&=f\,R\left\{\int_{0}^{\frac{0.75}{f}} I^2\:\text{d}t+\int_{0}^{\frac{0.25}{f} } 0\:\text{d}t\right\}\\\\
&=f\,I^2\,R\int_{0}^{\frac{0.75}{f}} \text{d}t\\\\
&=f\,I^2\,R\left[\vphantom{\frac{f\,V^2}{R}\int_{0}^{\frac{0.75}{f}} \text{d}t}t\right]_0^\frac{0.75}{f}\\\\
&=f\,I^2\,R\left[\vphantom{\frac{f\,V^2}{R}\int_{0}^{\frac{0.75}{f}} \text{d}t}\frac{0.75}{f}-0\right]
\\\\
&=\frac34 \,I^2\,R=\left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}I\right]^2\,R
\end{align*}$$

So \$I_{_\text{RMS}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{V}{R}\$ for a 75% duty cycle. Here, at 75% duty, \$I_{_\text{RMS}}\approx 43.3\:\text{mA}\$.

Just follow the same process to get the RMS values regardless of repeating waveform.

Take note that \$4.33\:\text{V}\,\cdot\,43.3\:\text{mA}\approx 187.5\:\text{mW}\$, also as expected.

Comment: \$\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\$ is better known as \$\sqrt{0.75}\$ for the purposes of this question

Comment: @user253751 I much prefer my use of integers. So do some mathematicians.

Answer (score 4):

" Ipk * sqrt(D), so if P= Vrms * Irms and Irms= 0.05A * sqrt(0.75) then P= 0.217W"

Vrms = Vpk * \$\sqrt{0.75}\$

Irms = Ipk * \$\sqrt{0.75}\$

P = Irms * Vrms = Vpk*Ipk * 0.75 = 0.1875W

Comment: True in this case (resistive load), so V and I have the same shape.  Not necessarily true in general if the load involved some L or C components as well as resistors.  That might be a good test for whether a certain way of thinking about the problem is useful.  (I think Andy Aka's answer is the most intuitive: power is applied 75% of the time, and when it's on it's `Vpk * Ipk`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, of course, and that's the way I would calculate it, but I wanted to apply the sqrt(D) formula the OP has.

Answer (score 3):

> *If \$P=V_{avg}\times I_{avg}\$*

It doesn't unless V and I are constant. Calculating power is quite simple: **average power**.

When the switch is closed the power is \$\frac{volts^2}{ohms}\$ = 250 mW.

The power is present for only 75% of the time hence, the **average power** is 187.5 mW.

> *if \$P=V_{RMS}×I_{RMS}\$ and \$I_{RMS}=0.05A×\sqrt{0.75}\$ then
> P=0.217W*

It doesn't because you assumed the voltage applied to the resistor was always 5 volts and clearly it isn't; it has the same "shape" as the current.